# Why disappear gameobjects when I move camera

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have model of building. I custom shaders fot its. Why when I move my camera - some gameobject disappear (although its must visible). GameObjects contains material with Standart shader rendering mode = transparent.
My Model near
http://prntscr.com/8z7yyd
and when more far:
http://prntscr.com/8z7z5u (two elements with red arrows - appear).

When I use shader unlit/Transparent Color - all element visible always visible when I move camera.

Comment: Maybe changing the "Clipping Plane->Near" property of the camera helps.

Comment: I have clipping planes with near = 0.1 and far = 1000000. I try change its - no good results

Comment: so to be sure, changing near to 0.000001 won't help?

Comment: This sounds like it might be a clipping problem with overlapping transparent objects. Has to do with depth sorting. Common problem with rendering transparent objects. (Engine can't decide which is in front). See [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/129285/transparent-shader-objects-disappear-on-certain-ca.html) for possible solution.

Comment: No help. If I use standart shader with rendering  mode = transparent, then game gameobjects disappear (even when move camera left, right). If I use standart shader with rendering mode = opaque , then gameobjects visible always.

Comment: If the problem were because of the near plane, then using an opaque shader would have the same result.

Comment: A minimal-"working" example project may be helpful to solve this problem

Comment: I solved problem: use standrart shader with rendering mode = transparent for objects with alpha and rendering mode =  opaque for objects without alpha.

Comment: @UtyashevaIrina Might want to post your discovery as an answer if you feel this question may have value to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem: use standard shader with rendering mode = transperent for objects with alpha and rendering mode = opaque for objects without alpha